# Does df.query return a deep copy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, deep-copy

I am querying a pandas data frame to return a df that only contains my male participants

```
df_query = df.query("sex == 'male'")
```

My question is, does this return a deep copy like one typically does when copying from a dataframe:

```
df.copy(deep=True)
```

That is if I make changes to df these will not be reflected in df_query? The pandas documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) is not, in my opinion, completely explicit on this.

Comment: Hi, I think this one follows with other `df[df['a']==1]`, it maybe a copy, or a reference, you dont know, and shouldn't base on it, because pandas has internal mechanism to decide when to copy, and when to reference it,

Comment: Thanks Phung Duy Phong. So to be clear I would have to do something like ```df_query = df.query("sex == 'male'").copy(deep=True)``` to ensure its correctly copied and behaves as I expect?

Comment: It returns shallow copies only. But that doesn't matter for scalar type columns.

Comment: After some bug in the pass with midification on data sliced from df, I always copy it in case I do want another copy to work with, and using `loc` if I want to modify the original df

Answer (score 0):

It depend on the "inplace" keyword argument. See [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

> inplace bool
>
> Whether to modify the DataFrame rather than creating a new one.

If you would like to be explicit you add it the the query arguments:

```
df_query = df.query("sex == 'male'", inplace=False)
```

(But since the default value is False there is no need, it will return a copy anyway.)

Comment: I assume the method, or the documentation, has been updated since I posted this question as I don’t believe this was the case 3 years ago but thanks for the answer.